# RP Automatic Updates

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+

Does Raspberry Pi working with Raspbian make any automatic updates without our permission? If yes, How to disable it?

Comment: The way you phrased it makes it sound like Rasbpian is doing something bad.

Comment: This is not intended, but it should not do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In fact Raspbian *does* have daily upgrades enabled by default; to check:

```
systemctl status apt-daily-upgrade.timer
```

The bit to play attention to is in the second line of output.  Between the two semi-colons it will say `enabled`:

```
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apt-daily-upgrade.timer; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
                                                              ^^^^^^^^
```

Or `disabled`, as it does here. Whether it does anything or not, you can check the time it was last run with:

```
stat -c %z /var/lib/apt/daily-lock
```

If it does do something, there should be a record of that in `/var/log/dpkg.log`.

To disable this:

```
sudo systemctl mask apt-daily-upgrade
sudo systemctl mask apt-daily
sudo systemctl disable apt-daily-upgrade.timer
sudo systemctl disable apt-daily.timer
```

The reason for using `mask` is to prevent these from being re-enabled by some dependency.

Notice those are two separate services; they both run `/usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily`, a shell script, with parameters `install` and `update`.

Comment: @Dougie, it's a sane default for an IoT device such as raspberry pi, one surelly wants to receive unnatended secrutiy patches to stay safe. And if you for whatever reason do not, well, it's easy to disable, nothing idiotic about that.

Comment: My system shows `Active: inactive (dead) since Sun 2019-12-29 06:58:54 AEDT; 5h 51min ago` but there is **NO evidence** that it has ever updated my OS.   

On another Pi (which I last manually updated over a month ago) now shows `17 packages can be upgraded.` so while this service runs it doesn't seem to actually do anything.

Comment: @Milliways The line to check is the second one, `Loaded:`.  The `Active` line will always be more or less the same unless you happen to check while the update/whatever is actually in progress, since this is not a persistent service.  I've edited in a bit about this.

Answer (score 5):

It does have that feature available, but it is **not** enabled by default.

https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades

Comment: You might want to check `systemctl status apt-daily-upgrade`... ;|